# Setting an event loop fails on IPython 8.22.1 / Python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Is the following reaction normal or is there a problem with my Python install. From the past hours of reading I just did, it really *should* work. Otherwise, what am I doing wrong?

```
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  8 2023, 05:06:43) [GCC 13.2.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.22.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import asyncio

In [2]: asyncio.get_event_loop()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 asyncio.get_event_loop()

File /usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py:677, in BaseDefaultEventLoopPolicy.get_event_loop(self)
    674     self.set_event_loop(self.new_event_loop())
    676 if self._local._loop is None:
--> 677     raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
    678                        % threading.current_thread().name)
    680 return self._local._loop

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.

In [3]: asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())

In [4]: asyncio.get_event_loop()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 1
----> 1 asyncio.get_event_loop()

File /usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/events.py:677, in BaseDefaultEventLoopPolicy.get_event_loop(self)
    674     self.set_event_loop(self.new_event_loop())
    676 if self._local._loop is None:
--> 677     raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
    678                        % threading.current_thread().name)
    680 return self._local._loop

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.
```

As you can see, line `[2]` says that there was no current event loop. So I created one on `[3]`. But on `[4]` there still isn't an event loop.

Is it me or is it the interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it may be useful for someone who ends up with the same issue. In a very surprising way, the problem was not with Python itself but with IPython. It was so surprising that it took me forever to figure it out.

At the time of me writing this, it's an open bug in IPython. So it really was the interpreter and not me: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/14297

The bug may be fixed by the time you read this.

Comment: Are you going to tell us what the problem was?

Comment: @PaulCornelius The problem was trying it inside of IPython. (https://ipython.org) You can see in my original code transcript that it not running in the original Python console but in IPython instead. Running the same code in the regular Python interpreter worked. I don't know why it failed in IPython. I since found it's a bug in IPython. I'm adding a note to that effect.